# How exactly works the supports() method of the Spring Validator interface?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following doubt about how works this validator example:

So I have this **search.jsp** page in which the user can search a product by 2 fields criteria (the product name and the category to which the product belongs):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Search</title>
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/include/head-include.jsp" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Search Products</h2>
    <div class="form-group form">
    <form:form name="input"  method="get"
        modelAttribute="product" action="products">
        <div>
            <label>Name: </label>
            <form:input type="text" path="name" class="form-control"  />
            <form:errors path="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Category:</label>
            <form:select path="category.id" class="form-control" >
                <form:option path="category.id" value="0" label="--- All Categories ---"/>
                <form:options path="category.id" items="${categories}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
            </form:select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control">
        </div>


    </form:form>
    </div>

    <h2>Search Results:</h2>

    <c:forEach var="product" items="${results}">
        <c:out value="${product.name}"/> <br/>
    </c:forEach>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, in the tutorial are introduced some restriction on the input of the 2 fields of the previous view implementing a **custom validator**. In the specific the user have to:

1) The user have to insert a product name or a category

2) The name lenght have to be at least composed by 3 characters.

3) The user can chose only by name or category but not on some other field of the **Product** model object

To implement this custom validator it is created this **ProductSearchValidator** class that implement the Spring **Validator** interface:

```
package com.packtpub.springmvc.chocolatestore;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.packtpub.springmvc.chocolatestore.model.Product;

@Component
public class ProductSearchValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Product.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);  
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Product product = (Product) target;
        String name = product.getName();
        if (!StringUtils.hasLength(name) && (product.getCategory() == null || product.getCategory().getId() == 0)) {
            errors.rejectValue("name", "required", "Either name or category is required");
        } else if ((product.getCategory() == null || product.getCategory().getId() == 0) && name.trim().length() < 3) {
            errors.rejectValue("name", "tooShort", "Please enter at least 3 letters");
        }

    }

}
```

From what I have understand the **supports()** method say if a specific instance of a class can be validate from this validator and the **validate()** method implement the specific validation logic.

Ok, the **validate()** method is pretty clear to me (it implement the previous 3 specified restriction).

The thing that I can't understand is how exactly does the **supports()** method

```
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Product.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);  
}
```

How exactly works? What represent its input parameter (**Class clazz**)? And what represent the returned boolean? (what is the meaning of the **Product.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)** evaluation?)

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the supports() method say if a specific instance of a class can be validate from this validator

No. It says if a specific class is supported by the validator. When validating an object, the object itself is not passed to `supports()`. What is passed to `supports()` is the class of the object.

So, before validating an instance of `Product`, Spring calls `supports()` with `Product.class` as argument.

Before validating an instance of `SubClassOfProduct`, Spring calls `supports()` with `SubClassOfProduct.class` as argument.

In both cases, since the Product.class is assignable from Product.class / SubclassOfProduct.class, the method returns true. If you tried to validate a User with that validator, it would return false. Indeed, you can do

```
Product p = someProductInstance;
```

You can also do

```
Product p = someSubClassOfProductInstance;
```

But you can't do

```
Product p = someUserInstance;
```

That's what `Product.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)` means.

See the relevant javadocs, which basically explain what I just explained:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29
- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html#supports-java.lang.Class-

Comment: as usual your explanations are perfect, tnx :-)